# TYPO3 login fail with \Saltedpasswords vs correct with felogin

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

My client has an old TYPO3 6.2 installation which has been rebuild in TYPO3 8.7.

In the old TYPO3 6.2 installation the `fe_users` table owns about 15.000 users with MD5/crypt(3) encrypted passwords (starting with *$1$*). The rebuild `fe_users` for the client in TYPO3 8.7 now has passwords based on the new crypt (starting with *$pbkdf2-sha256$*). So far, so good.

The old TYPO3 6.2 `fe_users` will be imported into the new database but I'm having issues on logging in with them using our own REST API (build in TYPO3 8.7), where the login using `felogin` are all successfull. After a successfull login by `felogin` the passwords are converted to their new encryption and I am able to login with the REST API. -- Logging in 15.000 users by `felogin` before the possibility of using the REST API is definitely not an option :)

The REST API does a comparison using `\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\`.

**tl;dr:**
How do I check for a successfull encryption by `\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\` without first forcing them the usage of `felogin`?

**Sample code of the REST API**

The *$byPasswordDecrypt* in the code below is a decrypted value of the password, which is send encrypted using [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('fe_users');
    $queryRows = $queryBuilder
            ->select('uid', 'username', 'password')
            ->from('fe_users')
            ->where(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('username', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($ogUser))
            )
            ->execute();

    // Fetch the rows
    $queryFetch = $user = $queryRows->fetch();

    // Now, check the salted-password from the database against the given password
    if (\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Utility\SaltedPasswordsUtility::isUsageEnabled('FE')) {
        $objSalt = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance($saltedPassword);
        if (is_object($objSalt)) {
            $success = $objSalt->checkPassword($byPasswordDecrypt, $queryFetch['password']);
        }
    }
```

If somebody could point me into the right direction to a successfull password-hash check, that would be absolutely great and I'd be so thankfull!

Comment: in a former version there was a scheduler task to convert all users from uncrypted password to md5 salted password. does that exist and work for you?

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. - Yes, I have tried the scheduler in both version. The passwords were already encrypted in the database (as MD5 crypt-3). Else the migration would be absolutely simple by running the scheduler. I'm unlucky as this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have managed to fix this problem myself and posting the solution to my own question, hoping to help someone else with this issue.*

TYPO3 6.2 (and probably lower) is hashing the passwords using a MD5-hash, starting with *$1$*. If everything set-up correctly, TYPO3 8.7 will hash the passwords using something like *$pbkdf2-sha256$*.

To check for old passwords, you should make an instance of the  `TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\Md5Salt`. After you've done a successfull check using `checkPassword` by this instance, I'd recommend you update your database table using the given password and encrypting it by using `\TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory`.

**An examplecode for checking the old MD5 encrypted password:**

```
$md5PasswordProcessor = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Saltedpasswords\\Salt\\Md5Salt');

$sampleLoginData = array(
    'uname' => $usernameSample
    'uident' => $unencryptedPassword,
    'status' => 'login'
);

$frontEndUserAuth = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Frontend\\Authentication\\FrontendUserAuthentication');
$frontEndUserAuth->checkPid = false;

$info = $frontEndUserAuth->getAuthInfoArray();
$info['db_user']['username_column'] = 'email';

$user_db = $frontEndUserAuth->fetchUserRecord($info['db_user'], $sampleLoginData['uname']);

$passwordByMd5 = $md5PasswordProcessor->checkPassword($byPasswordDecrypt, $user_db['password']);

if($passwordByMd5 === true) {
    // Check is correct, update your database here by, for example:
    $objSalt = \TYPO3\CMS\Saltedpasswords\Salt\SaltFactory::getSaltingInstance(null);
    $saltedPassword = $objSalt->getHashedPassword($unencryptedPassword);

    // And your queryBuilder should be written here
}
```

I hope I helped anyone else out, having this problem.